# How to think of affine maps composition.

Tags: linear-algebra

Say one has two affine maps in the form $f_1=A_1x+b_1$ and $f_2=A_2x+b_2$ with $A_1, A_2 \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Keeping to this notation - i.e. without using extended matrix notation - how would one write $f_1
\circ f_2$? I think it should be equal to $A_1A_2 +(A_2b_1+b_2)$ i.e. the linear part and the translation stay "separated" but I'm rusty in linear algebra and would like someone to confirm my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(f_1\circ f_2)(x):=f_1(f_2(x))=f_1(A_2x+b_2)=A_1A_2x+A_1b_2+b_1=\\=(A_1A_2)x+(A_1b_2+b_1)$$